# Why isn't this onPress navigation working?

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native, Expo and React Navigation version 5.

Here's my app root.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import IndexScreen from "./src/screens/IndexScreen";
import ShowScreen from "./src/screens/ShowScreen";
import CreateScreen from "./src/screens/CreateScreen";
import { Provider } from "./src/context/BlogContext";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// cannot navigate to create screen on press of header? research on sunday

function App() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Index">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Index"
          component={IndexScreen}
          options={{
            title: "Blogs",
            headerRight: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation("CreateScreen")}>
                <Feather name="plus" style={styles.icon} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Show" component={ShowScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Create" component={CreateScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "black",
    marginRight: 15,
  },
});

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

I am trying to add an onPress function to an icon in the header. I do not have access to the navigation prop in the app root apparently, so I am using the useNavigation hook provided by React Navigation. However, I get a 'could not find a navigation object' error from Expo. I'm stumped, and need to find a way to navigate to the CreateScreen using the icon in the header. I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

For useNavigation hook to work you should call it inside NavigationContainer.
And if your requirement is using the navigation in onPress of options you can do like below.

```
   options={({navigation})=>({
        title: "Blogs",
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("CreateScreen")}>
            <Feather name="plus" style={styles.icon} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      })}
```

This will provide you access to the navigation prop and you can navigate to the other screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you give me some insight on how and where to call the useNavgiation hook? Because, where it currently is, it appears to be way out of scope. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use navigation hook is for purposes like a button within the navigation stack, something which is not a screen that has navigation prop but within the container. If you want to access navigation outside the container you will have to use the navigationRef not the hook.